# Distinta reacción al método prompt según el navegador

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-web

El método `prompt` detiene la ejecución del *script* hasta que obtiene una respuesta, propiedad que me interesa para ciertas pruebas, pero parece que en algunos navegadores como firefox, *renderiza* la página después de cada `prompt`, pero otros como Chrome se espera a que se respondan todos.
¿Hay alguna manera sencilla de que en todos reaccione igual que firefox?
Aquí os dejo un ejemplo, reacciona distinto según el navegador (en Chrome se muestra como NO quiero), me gustaría que mostrara los resultados a medida que vas respondiendo, y no todo de golpe al final.

```js
    function escribir(texto){
        document.body.innerHTML+=texto+"<br>";
    }

    var nombre = prompt("Nombre?");
    escribir(nombre);

    var edad = prompt("Edad?");
    escribir(edad);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar setTimeout para "separar" la ejecución de los dos prompts y así dar tiempo al hilo que renderiza la página a actualizar la vista:

```js
function escribir(texto){
        document.body.innerHTML+=texto+"<br>";
    }

    var nombre = prompt("Nombre?");
    escribir(nombre);

    setTimeout(() => {
      var edad = prompt("Edad?");
      escribir(edad);
    })
```

Comment: Ya lo pensé pero no es lo que ando buscando, gracias.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví, ¿qué es lo que estás buscando?

Comment: @Triby Busco saber si existe, por ejemplo, alguna otra instrucción que le obligue a renderizar, y no tener que concatenar capas de setTimeouts por cada prompt que quiera usar.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví, podrías intentar con [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame), pero no parece muy viable.

Comment: @Triby Buena idea, pero no me ha funcionado, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Personalmente la solución que me parece más elegante es usar un modal hecho con HTML, evitando el uso de prompt

Answer (score 0):

Como sugiere @PabloLozano en su respuesta, cada que ejecutes un `prompt()` que deba actualizar algo en pantalla, "dale tiempo" al navegador para que muestre los cambios, colocándolo dentro de un `setTimeout()`.

Si se trata de muchas peticiones, puedes crear una función para evitar anidaciones.

```js
function escribir(texto){
    document.body.innerHTML += texto+"<br>";
}

/**
 * @param string pregunta       Texto que aparecerá en prompt()
 * @param function callback     Función que debe ejecutarse al finalizar el prompt()
 */
function promptCb(pregunta, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let resp = prompt(pregunta);
        // Ejecutar función enviando respuesta como parámetro
        callback(resp);
    });
}

promptCb("¿Cuál es tu nombre?", escribir);
promptCb("¿Cuál es tu edad?", escribir);
```

Probé el fragmento de código en Chrome y funcionó correctamente.